# NSSearchField in Custom View, Focus Ring is cut

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nsview, nssearchfield

I have a NSSearchField in a Custom View (Xcode 4, Mac OS 10.6).
The underlying View seems to limit the height of the Search Field to the 22px and therefore, when the SearchField gets Focus, the Focus Ring is cut (see below).

How do I get this right (get the whole Focus Ring), what am I missing?

[image]

EDIT: Really nobody has suggestions how to avoid this (besides using a "normal" NSTextField)?

Comment: I had the same issue.  I do believe it's a bug that is in Xcode 4.

Comment: Hum, and how did you resolve that issue? Did you fall back to xcode 3?

Comment: I actually just dumped it and switched to a [custom subclass of NSTextField](http://cocoatricks.com/2010/06/a-better-looking-text-field/).

Comment: Hum, ok, guess this is the easiest way. Maybe i'll try subclassing NSSearchField (because I like the look and feel), and maybe it'll work..